# Reading unknown lines with ReadLine

Tags: c#

I want to add strings(abc, def,ghi) to a list of type string,

```
       List<string> names = new List<string>();
```

Reading unknown number of lines till user enters an Enterkey

All the strings are added to the list 
           when I use a string(line in below example) and assign it the output of  Console.ReadLine() and check if its Empty or not

```
       string line;
       while ((!string.IsNullOrEmpty(line =Console.ReadLine())))
        {

            names.Add(line);         //This works abc, def,ghi are added to the list

        }
```

But this doesn't work when I directly compare the Output of Console.ReadLine()

```
         while ((!string.IsNullOrEmpty(Console.ReadLine())))
        {

            names.Add(Console.ReadLine());         //only def is  added to the list

        }
```

I could not identify the issue here.

Comment: In your second example, where do you ever define or set `line`?  I don't see how that code would be adding *any* input to the list.

Comment: you should probably read this http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic

Comment: @David I have edited it

Comment: Pretend you're a computer and go through this step-by-step, evaluating from the inside of the innermost parentheses outwards. Don't skip any steps. While doing that, think carefully about how `ReadLine` works.

Answer (score 1):

Why not a simple infinite loop with `break`:

```
List<string> names = new List<string>();

while (true) {
  string line = Console.ReadLine();

  if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(line)) // break on Enter - i.e. on empty line
    break;

  names.Add(line); // otherwise add into the list
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Consider what `Console.ReadLine()` does and how your loop works:

```
while ((!string.IsNullOrEmpty(Console.ReadLine()))) // read abc, but don't do anything with it
{
    names.Add(Console.ReadLine()); // read def, add it to the list
}
```

Your loop is essentially skipping every other line of input, because each iteration of the loop reads *two* lines of input, but adds only *one* of those lines to the list.  This is precisely why one would store that input in a variable:

```
string input = Console.ReadLine();
while (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(input))
{
    names.Add(input);
    input = Console.ReadLine();
}
```

(Or, if you prefer, the original example you posted.  Though personally I find variable assignment in an operation like that to be distasteful, but that's a matter of personal preference.)

Answer (score 0):

In the second example, you're still using names.Add(line) when line has no value. Also, while having the console take an input, that value isn't saved anywhere.

With your edit it takes two inputs instead of just one.